# Using Core Data Find or Create Pattern in Generic Method

Tags: ios, core-data, insert-update

I have a Generic method which adds data from a JSON into a Managed Object based on the keys in the JSON and in the entity.
I have read Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) but I somehow can't seem to walk through the data after the fetch in order to apply the Find or Create pattern.
I don't want to use three nested loops to do that, is there another way? 
Should I be looping over `jsonArrayData` or `entityMatchingNames`

```
- (void) safeSetValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSArray *)jsonArrayData : (NSNumber *) entitySpecifier{

    //Flag to determine entity name
    NSString *entityName;
    NSString *idName;
    if([entitySpecifier isEqual:@1]){

        entityName = @"Zones";
        idName=@"zoneID";
    }else if([entitySpecifier isEqual:@2]){
        entityName = @"Categories";
        idName=@"categoryID";
    }else if ([entitySpecifier isEqual:@3]){
        entityName = @"Companies";
        idName=@"companyID";
    }

    //get entity
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.elRehabCoreData.managedObjectContext];

    //get attributes of entity in core data
    NSDictionary *entityAttributes = [entity attributesByName];



    // Get the ids from json in sorted order.
    NSMutableArray *entityIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *jsonValues in jsonArrayData) {
        id value = [jsonValues objectForKey:idName];
        [entityIDs addObject:value];
    }

    [entityIDs sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];


    // create the fetch request to get all Entities matching the IDs
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSString *filter = @"(%K IN %@)";

    [fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: filter, idName, entityIDs]];

    // Make sure the results are sorted as well.
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
     @[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: idName ascending:YES] ]];

    // Execute the fetch.

    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *entityMatchingNames = [self.elRehabCoreData.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];


    int i = 0;

    for (NSDictionary *keyedValues in jasonArrayData) {

        i++;
        //Create NSManagedObject
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = nil;

        //insert
        managedObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.elRehabCoreData.managedObjectContext];


        //loop over entities in core data
        for (NSString *attribute in entityAttributes) {

            id value = [keyedValues objectForKey:attribute];

            if (value == nil) {
                // Don't attempt to set nil, or you'll overwite values in self that aren't present in keyedValues
                continue;
            }
            NSAttributeType attributeType = [[entityAttributes objectForKey:attribute] attributeType];

            if ((attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
                value = [value stringValue];
            } else if (((attributeType == NSInteger16AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger32AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger64AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType)) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
                value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value integerValue]];
            } else if ((attributeType == NSFloatAttributeType) &&  ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
                value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
            }


            /*Add values for valid attributes */

            //set value
            [managedObject setValue:value forKey:attribute];



        }

    }

    //save core data stack
    [self.elRehabCoreData saveContext];
    NSLog(@"%@ and #managed objects are: %i ", @"Saved and Finished ", i);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an if condition like in http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1 tutorial that checks if the count for the JSONArray is the same as that of the fetchedArray, then use the managedObject from the fetchedArray otherwise insert a new ManagedObject.
This method is possible only if both arrays are sorted in exactly the same manner.

```
for (NSDictionary *keyedValues in sortedJSONArray) {


    //Create NSManagedObject
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = nil;
    int updateInsert = 0;

   //This is the part that determines whether to update or insert.
    if(entityMatchingNames.count > i ){
        managedObject = [entityMatchingNames objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"In Managed Object %@, In JSON %@", [managedObject valueForKey:idName], [keyedValues valueForKey:idName] );
        if ([[managedObject valueForKey:idName] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[keyedValues valueForKey:idName] integerValue]]]) {

            updateInsert = 1;
        }

    }else{
        //insert
         managedObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.elRehabCoreData.managedObjectContext];
            updateInsert = 1;
    }

    i++;

    //loop over entities in core data
    for (NSString *attribute in entityAttributes) {

        id value = [keyedValues objectForKey:attribute];

        if (value == nil) {
            // Don't attempt to set nil, or you'll overwite values in self that aren't present in keyedValues
            continue;
        }
        NSAttributeType attributeType = [[entityAttributes objectForKey:attribute] attributeType];

        if ((attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
            value = [value stringValue];
        } else if (((attributeType == NSInteger16AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger32AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger64AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType)) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value integerValue]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSFloatAttributeType) &&  ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
        }


        /*Add values for valid attributes */

        //set value
        if (updateInsert) {
            [managedObject setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        }




    }

}
```